# Can't run Spring Tool Suite on a Mac

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, spring-tool-suite

I get this when I try and run the Spring Tool Suite on Yosemite:

To open “STS” you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime.

Click “More Info…” to visit the legacy Java SE 6 download website.

The more info brings me to this apparently defunct page:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: The message is pretty clear. You have to install Java 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page isn't defunct, though for some reason I couldn't get it to load in Safari at all, and it was screwed up using https in Firefox. However, http in Firefox did work:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

There's your Java 6.

In some cases you can (and should) use Oracle Java 7 or 8 instead, at http://java.com; try that first. It can coexist with Apple Java 6 if you still need to install that.

Comment: Yep that worked. I had already installed Java 8 which did not solve the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This message is coming from the installer, right? It requires a JDK 6 to run. STS itself doesn't require JDK 6 to run. You can just use your JDK8 to run STS. Download the latest version of STS as a tar.gz, extract it, and run it. It will pick the JDK8, if installed on your machine. No need to install JDK6 from Apple if you se the tar.gz instead of the dmg and the installer.

Btw: we are not shipping these outdated installers anymore, the latest versions are coming as tar.gz for Mac only.

Comment: Martin, I did in fact download the tar.gz file from the start. I got it here: "https://spring.io/tools/sts/all". Also, I had in fact, installed the JDK8, and it still failed. I had to download the JDK 6 to finally get it to run.

Comment: That is strange. Is STS actually running on that installed JDK6 then?